# How do I get and use a class type from a Java class that I've dynamically created at runtime using ASM?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, type-conversion, metaprogramming, java-bytecode-asm

I'd like extend the class, get a class literal, use it as a type parameter, or cast to it.

I already have a workaround, but I'm still curious.

Currently I can define a class at runtime with ASM, create an instance with `Object` type and invoke its methods with reflection, but I don't know how to use it as a class type.

Granted, the compiler doesn't know about classes defined at runtime, but in this case *I* know about it, and I think that I see it hidden in the ASMified .java file (example below). How can convince the compiler that it actually *does* know the class type at compile time?

Thanks for taking a look,

-Julian

Example of an ASMified class B: bytecode-generating code that spoofs `class B{String hello = "Hello B!"}`:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.*;
//import org.objectweb.asm.attrs.*;
public class BDump implements Opcodes {

public static byte[] dump () throws Exception {

ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
FieldVisitor fv;
MethodVisitor mv;
AnnotationVisitor av0;

cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_SUPER, "B", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

{
fv = cw.visitField(0, "hello", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
fv.visitEnd();
}
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(0, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitLdcInsn("Hello B!");
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, "B", "hello", "Ljava/lang/String;");
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
mv.visitEnd();
}
cw.visitEnd();

return cw.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a class at compile time which doesn't exist at compile time.  What you can do is

- use a class or interface which exists at compile time but is replaced at runtime with the desired implementation.
- use an interface which is available at compile time but is only implemented at runtime.
- use reflection to call the constructor/methods at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. It begs more questions:) Where is the breakdown, exactly? Since there is nothing *I* don't know about the class at compile time, I naively expect to be able to provide the compiler with a spoofed version of whatever it should expect, but I couldn't find a "Java Compiler For Dummies" on the web.

Comment: Generating byte code is something which few developers with ten years experience have done whereas you should understand the basics of how to use compiler after a few months.  I am a little confused as to your familiarity with Java.

Comment: Noob status here, learning Java through some fun projects. I know some of the basics about compilers, e.g. lexer/scanner-parser-analyzer phases, but I can't seem to find out how *exactly* ASTs are used and what *exactly* happens in each phase so that I might be able to circumvent whatever check is throwing the error.